# Какой проект можно взять по js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно придумать проект с использованием js, html, css
в гугле очень старые проекты, которые все могут сделать

Comment: Сделай ОС на js

Comment: ты серьезно? -_-

Comment: ты же написал что в  гугле очень старые проекты, которые **все могут сделать**. Значит тебе тот, который не все могут сделать... ну так вот тебе.... в чём проблема?) кстати ОС на js вполне реально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделать что-то похожее на wow.js,если уже так сверстай сам страничку только со своим дизайном(вот тебе html,css),и js сделать саму библиотеку